# Braintree's processing fee

Tags: ruby, braintree

I'd like to get the amount of Braintree's processing fee for any transaction that has been made using the API. Looking at the response object of [Braintree::Transaction.sale](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby) which can be found at [Braintree::Transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/ruby), I can't seem to find it. So, where can I get it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Braintree processing fee is fixed at 2.9% + $.30 per transaction:
https://www.braintreepayments.com/pricing

Given that you can implement a small helper method, like the following:

```
def calc_braintree_fee(amount)
    return amount*0.029 + 0.3
end
```

Comment: I sort of know the calculation. I need to get it from the API per transaction so that I don't have to calculate it. This is possible with PayPal and WePay but not Braintree. Besides, Braintree gives certain discount for the members, so, there're other calculations involved. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Along with not being accurate for every customer, this calculation also likely will lead to rounding errors down the road. Braintree rounds down to the nearest cent on each transaction.